# Minimal complete definition with dependent functions

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the following typeclass (irrelevant methods omitted):

```
class Initializable a where
    initialize :: IO a
    initialize = return initializePure

    {# convenience method for implementations, not to be called from outside #}
    initializePure :: a

data Foo = Foo

instance Initializable Foo where
    initializePure = Foo

data Bar = Bar

instance Initializable Bar where
    initialize = initializeBar
```

Some implementations need `IO` to initialize themselves, some don't.

This code gives a warning:

```
No explicit implementation for
  ‘initializePure’
In the instance declaration for ‘Initializable Bar’
```

I have tried to add a `MINIMAL` pragma like this:

```
{-# MINIMAL initializePure | initialize #-}
```

But then I get a different warning:

```
The MINIMAL pragma does not require:
  ‘initializePure’
but there is no default implementation.
In the class declaration for ‘Initializable’
```

My intent is to have `Initializable` by providing *either* `initialize` or `initializePure`, but only using `initialize` outside of the definition.

How do I compile the code cleanly?

Comment: What do you expect `initializePure :: Bar` to be, in the last case? There is no implementation for that: not in the instance, and not in the class.

Comment: @chi I don't expect `initializePure` to be called except from `initialize`. I've amended the question to include that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is quite right to warn about this, since it *cannot* be possible to have `initialisePure` on a type that can only be initialised with IO.

The only way to make this safe is to separate the two cases; the simplest possibility would be to have *two* classes:

```
class Initialisable a where
  initialise :: IO a

class Initialisable a => PureInitialisable a where
  initialisePure :: a

data Foo = Foo

instance Initialisable Foo where
  initialise = return Foo
instance PureInitialisable Foo where
  initialisePure = Foo

data Bar = Bar
initialiseBar :: IO Bar
initialiseBar = undefined

instance Initialisable Bar where
  initialise = initialiseBar
```

You can't give a default implementation for `PureInitialisable`, because it just *doesn't exist* for some types, like `Bar`. But if you turn on `DefaultSignatures`, you can give a default for `Initialisable` that kicks in when the type also happens to be `PureInitialisable`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class Initialisable a where
  initialise :: IO a

  default initialise :: PureInitialisable a => IO a
  initialise = return initialisePure
```

For types like `Foo`, this lets you write

```
instance PureInitialisable Foo where initialisePure = Foo
instance Initialisable Foo
```

which is slightly shorter.

An alternative might be to make the monad in which initialisation happens customisable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Initialisable a where
  type InitialisationM a :: *
  type InitialisationM a = a
  initialise :: InitialisationM a

instance Initialisable Foo where
  initialise = Foo

instance Initialisable Bar where
  type InitialisationM Bar = IO Bar
  initialise = initialiseBar
```

Comment: ...and you can use `DefaultSignatures` to still have a default implementation of `initialise` for those types that happen to also be instances of `PureInitialisable`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That extension suits me perfectly, want to make that an answer?

Comment: @Koterpillar I've edited this answer to mention it, instead.